# vim key mapping to existing key

Tags: vim, configuration, keyboard-shortcuts

I am trying to map a key combination to an existing key combination and added this in .vimrc file:

```
noremap <C-A> <C-TAB>
```

what I want to do is to let <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> does exactly what <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> does in my Vim environment. But it is not working. Could someone point out what I did wrongly, thanks.

Comment: What does `<C-Tab>` do in your environment? Maybe it's easier to map `<C-a>` directly to the command executed by `<C-Tab>`. This key sequence usually doesn't work in Terminals, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "nore" on the front stands for "no recurse", i.e. it won't "recurse" to invoke C-TAB as a command.  I believe just `map <C-A> <C-TAB>` should work, if I grok the question (and vim...).  See `:help map-commands` for some useful explanation.

I'm not sure whether you really want to do this though, as it could interfere with other commands.